# How do they draw the charts/graphs on stackoverflow?

Tags: charts, svg, vector-graphics, vml

I spent ages learning VML and creating charts for a website once, but since VML only works in Internet Explorer, it's not much good these days.

I notice stackoverflow has graphs on my profile page, under 'reputation', but I wasnt able to see how they did it.

Can anyone suggest a way to create client-side charts or diagrams, that work in all browsers? I do not want to use the server-side method whereby an image file is created on the fly. I may wish to interact with the chart with JavaScript too.

[Edit - it's not just charts I want to draw. Perhaps little diagrams too!]

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is excellent.

Comment: I was going to suggest SVG, but flot looks amazing.

Comment: SVG requires users download and install a plugin i believe?

Comment: SVG works natively with pretty much everything but IE, which has VML instead.  Google have a JS compatibility layer they're releasing (not quite sure if it's out yet) that emulates SVG in IE using VML - much the same way as ExCanvas simulates a canvas.  So yes, you can use SVG now, without a plugin, and even in IE if you're feeling brave.

Answer (score 3):

Google created a great public [chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) for this purpose.

Examples:

[image: line chart] [image: pie chart] [image]

Comment: Great, I need to find a use for that ;-).

Comment: I didn't think you could interact with Google Charts once they were rendered..?

Comment: I have used these before - they are great! But in the question I did say I wanted a client-side process.

Answer (score 3):

In [episode 24](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/podcast-24/) of the stack overflow podcast it is mentioned that jQuery is used. A commentor on [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/i-dont-give-a-damn-about-my-reputation/) article suggests that [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is the library used.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). You can do all sorts of sophisticated things with minimal effort - by you at design time and by you server at run time. Nice.

Comment: I have used these before - they are great! But in the question I did say I wanted a client-side process.